# What are the political implications of buying a russian airgun as a european citizen?

Tags: european-union, russian-federation, guns

I'm considering buying a russian-made airgun, the Baikal mp 61.
I'm a European citizen and usually I try to support companies in Europe.
In this case, I don't find any other western designs that provide the same features.

Now, tensions with Russia have a little bit escalated since they took over Crimea, and I'm wondering what I'm supporting if I buy a weapon from a Russian company.

So the question is, by buying something from Baikal, what is the political cost of it?

Thanks,

Comment: I guess you'd need to better define what you mean by "political cost". Are you asking about legality, or if this would get you put on some sort of "list"? Or just more general arguments for why one should "Buy European"?

Comment: the European Union and Russia are in conflict regarding the annexion of Crimea by Russia, a civilian plane was even shot down, so there is a conflict of egos there. The UE set up an embargo (a policy). However I see that it's still possible to buy airguns made in Russia. I  would like to understand why it's still possible, and what is the reason that the embargo prevents French farmers to sell apples but not Russia to sell airguns. And in particular in buying this product, am I going against the intention of the embargo

Comment: Ah, that's much clearer. If you ask "why it's still possible, and what is the reason that the embargo prevents French farmers to sell apples but not Russia to sell airguns?", then that would definitely be an on-topic question.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you have to worry about a *political* cost to yourself. The amount of money is trivial on the international scale, and the place to use and show an airgun is *away from the public.*

- At least *some* European countries have strict safety and testing requirements for airguns which approach the limits of the weapons laws. Having an non-certified weapon above the threshold is a serious offense even if a certified weapon with the same power would be legal to own.
  [Legislation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Air_gun_laws) and thresholds differ from country to country.
- You might have noticed that even "toys" got safer in recent decades. Compare the bullets fired by the [old](https://www.playmobil.de/us-kavallerie-superset/3408-A.html) Playmobil cannon with those from the [new](https://www.playmobil.de/kavalleriewagen-mit-kanone/5249-A.html) cannon -- larger projectiles with a softer tip.
- If you buy from a reputable shop in your country, those requirements should have been taken care of. If you are importing yourself, things could get problematic.